# Geometric Interpretation of a full rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Suppose we have a full rank square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that each row (or each column) corresponds to a point in $n$-dimensional space. So the rank($A$) = $n$.

If we join these points to form an $n$-vertices shape, what is the geometric interpretation of this shape? i.e. What are the properties we can determine about this shape knowing that the original matrix $A$ was full rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to $n=3$ we can give a geometrical meaning to a full rank matrix that is to a set of $n$ linearly indipendent vectors.

Notably for $n=2$, $2$ linearly indipendent vectors are not multiple one of each other and for $n=3$, $3$ linearly indipendent vectors are not coplanar.

But for $n>3$ we can't visualize this situation geometrically, we need to use others method to figure out whether linearly independence holds.